# OpenMP reduction on SSE2 vector

Tags: openmp, sse, simd

I want to compute the average of an image (3 channels of interest + 1 alpha channel we ignore here) for  each channel using SSE2 intrinsics. I tried that:

```
  __m128 average = _mm_setzero_ps();

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:average)
  for(size_t k = 0; k < roi_out->height * roi_out->width * ch; k += ch)
  {
    float *in = ((float *)temp) + k;
    average += _mm_load_ps(in);
  }
```

But I get this error with GCC: `user-defined reduction not found for average`.

Is that possible with SSE2 ? What's wrong ?

**Edit**

This works:

```
float sum[4] = { 0.0f };

#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum[:4])
for(size_t k = 0; k < roi_out->height * roi_out->width * ch; k += ch)
{
  float *in = ((float *)temp) + k;
  for (int i = 0; i < ch; ++i) sum[i] += in[i];
}

const __m128 average = _mm_load_ps(sum) / ((float)roi_out->height * roi_out->width);
```

Comment: You should provide a minimum working and compilable example if you want people to try to improve your code. And maybe you should have a look on #pragma omp declare reduction. Obviously gcc complains it is not defined.

Comment: But the sum reduction is built-in isn't it ? Declaring a reduction is only for custom operations, AFAIK.

Comment: `_mm_load_ps(in);` is only safe if `in` is 16-byte aligned.  It won't be if `ch=3`.  Also, letting the compiler auto-vectorize with `omp simd` will let it hopefully use multiple accumulators to hide FP-add latency.  If it uses 3 or 6 accumulators, it could maybe avoid overlap and make use of all 12 or 24 vector elements, and sort out the shuffling at the end to add the right elements together into 3 different sums.  (Or maybe you should do that yourself if possible for better single-threaded performance by a factor or 3 or 4 (addps latency) times 4/3 for not wasting an element.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. What is the right loading method then ?

Comment: `_mm_loadu_ps(in)`.  Or like I suggested, manually vectorize with 3 or 6 vectors (because `3*4 = 12 = lcm(channels, vector_width)` to line up channels with vector elements), so you only ever need aligned loads with no overlap.  You may be able to get OpenMP to help you parallelize a manually-vectorized loop, but I'd highly recommend it for a speedup of ~4x for each thread (or less if you start hitting DRAM or L3 per-core bandwidth bottlenecks, but on a machine with few cores like a desktop or laptop you should get a big speedup and only need a couple cores to saturate DRAM.)

Comment: Is your image actually of type `float`? (what is `temp` before casting?)

Comment: @chtz yes it is `float`

Comment: @PeterCordes that's strange, `_mm_load_ps` is used multiple times in the code, it never complained. I know the software copies the image in 16-byte aligned, the structure of the picture is RGBaRGBaRGBa…

Comment: Oh, that's fine then, your data is aligned.  Your question said your image had 3 channels, so I assumed `ch=3`.  You didn't say there was an alpha channel.  You still want to use multiple accumulators to hide FP latency, especially if your data might be hot in L2 or L3 cache.  But 16 bytes per 4 cycles is probably still a worse bottleneck than memory.

Comment: Reductions are not predefined for simd vector types. You could file an enhancement request on gcc's bugzilla, it seems like a sensible and easy extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user-define a custom reduction like this:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction \
    (addps:__m128:omp_out+=omp_in) \
    initializer(omp_priv=_mm_setzero_ps())
```

And then use it like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(addps:average)
for(size_t k = 0; k < size * ch; k += ch)
{
  average += _mm_loadu_ps(data+k);
}
```

I think, most importantly, openmp needs to know how to get a neutral element (here `_mm_setzero_ps()`) for your reduction.

Full working example: https://godbolt.org/z/Fpqttc

Interesting link: http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html#User-definedreductions

Comment: In that Godbolt output, the actual `addps` loop that each thread runs is pretty hard to find.  It seems to be at the very bottom of the `get_average(float const*, unsigned long) [clone ._omp_fn.0]:` that the main function passes as an arg to `GOMP_parallel`.  It uses `addps` with one accumulator, bottlenecking on FP add latency instead of throughput, and thus achieving about 1/8 (Skylake) to 1/3 (Haswell) of the throughput per thread that it could with data hot in cache.  I suspect that even when data comes from DRAM, it would help some to unroll with multiple accumulators, especially with HT.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I played a bit with an unrolled version: https://godbolt.org/z/ZJ5JGs (untested, does not handle cases where size is not divisible by 4, ...)

Comment: Normally clang knows how to unroll with multiple accumulators.  IDK why it doesn't manage that here, even with `-ffast-math` :/